# How can I get the values corresponding to a list in Python without writing many if/else statements?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list of values

`['small', 'medium', 'large', 'extralarge']`

that I would like to map into the numbers `[1,2,3,4]`

with `small` corresponding to `1`, `medium` corresponding to `2`, `large` corresponding to `3`, and `extralarge` corresponding to `4`.

How can I efficiently do such a functional mapping for a new value `x` without needing to do something like

```
if x == "small":
    print(1)
elif x == "medium":
...
```

Comment: `print(next(i for i, v in enumerate(sizes, start=1) if v == x))`

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary:

```py
sizes = ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'extralarge']
mapping = {size: value for value, size in enumerate(sizes, 1)}
```

Then for some `x`,

```py
print(mapping[x])
```

Which will print the value 1, 2, 3, or 4, based on the value of `x` being a some size like "small", "medium", etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate()` to bind each string to an index:

```py
for idx, item in enumerate(data, start=1):
    if x == item:
        print(idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through them as @BrokenBenchmark suggests. However, you should consider whether a list is the most optimal data structure for your purpose; as @ddejohn suggests, perhaps a dictionary would suit better your purposes as its structure is literally a set of mapped key:value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have two lists then one way to create dictionary is to use zip:

```
names = ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'extralarge']
nums = [1,2,3,4]

mapping = dict(zip(names, nums))
```

If you don't have numbers list and need one number corresponding to the name at the time then you can take advantage of indices. Simple helper function:

```
names = ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'extralarge']

def get_value(name, list_):
    return list_.index(name) + 1

print(get_value('medium', names))    # prints 2
```

Name lookup in similar fashion could look like:

```
def get_name(num, list_):
    return list_[num-1]

print(get_name(2, names))    # prints 'medium'
```

If you append new names to names list then you don't need to update other parts of your code.